# How to find the irrational roots of a 4th degree polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

Please help me to solve this 4th-degree polynomial which may have irrational roots. I failed to solve it using the rational zeros' method. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Here is the equation
$$105.65x^4 - 6x^3 - 6x^2 - 6x - 106 = 0.$$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: For polynomials of degree 3 and 4, there are formulas (like the quadratic formula, but more complicated) to find the roots. Look up the Cardano formulas (for degree 3) and Ferrari's method (for degree 4).

Comment: In general, to find the zeros of a polynomial, you need to use an iterative approach like bisection or Newton's method.

Comment: @D.B.: but not in particular.

Comment: You can type it into [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10565x%5E4-600x%5E3-600x%5E2-600x-10600%3D0) and click on exact forms.  They are a mess.  I multiplied by $100$ to clear the decimals so it would take the coefficients as exact.

Answer (score 2):

Hoping that you are not afraid by the computation of the discriminant (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)) and considering, as Ross Millikan did,
$$f(x)=10565 x^4-600 x^3-600 x^2-600 x-10600=0$$ you should find
$$\Delta=-361000281458201144000000000$$ So,  the equation has two distinct real roots and two complex conjugate non-real roots.

Now, using inspection
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & f(x) \\
 -2 & 162040 \\
 -1 & 565 \\
 0 & -10600 \\
 1 & -1835 \\
 2 & 150040
\end{array}
\right)$$ So, the first real root is  just above $-1$ and the second one just above $1$.

For the first one, let $x=y-1$ to get
$$f(y-1)=10565 y^4-42860 y^3+64590 y^2-43460 y+565$$ Since we look close to $y=0$, consider only the last terms and write
$$f(y-1)\sim -43460 y+565=0 \implies y=\frac{113}{8692}\implies x_1=-\frac{8579}{8692}\approx -0.987000$$

Doing the same for the second root
$$f(y+1)=10565 y^4+41660 y^3+60990 y^2+38660 y-1835$$
$$f(y+1)\sim 38660 y-1835=0 \implies y=\frac{367}{7732}\implies x_2=\frac{8099}{7732}\approx 1.04747$$ while the exact solutions would be $-0.986741$ and $1.04428$.

We could improve it including the terms in $y^2$ and get
$$x_1=-1+\frac{4346-\sqrt{17427982}}{12918}\approx -0.986738$$
$$x_2=1+\frac{\sqrt{19422622}-3866}{12198}\approx 1.04436$$ which are not exact but better.

**Edit**

*This has been added for your curiosity.*

What I did is basically to write the truncated Taylor series around $x=-1$ and $x=1$.

Sooner or later, you will learn that, better than with Taylor series, we can locally approximate function using [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant). Built around $x=a$, the simplest one is given by
$$f(x)=\frac{f(a)+\frac{ 2 f'(a)^2-f(a) f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}(x-a)}{1-\frac{
   f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}(x-a)}$$ So, setting the numerator equal to $0$, this gives as an approximation
$$x=a+\frac{2 f(a) f'(a)}{f(a) f''(a)-2 f'(a)^2}$$ Applied to the problem, this would give
$$x_1=-\frac{36554467}{37045565}\approx -0.986743$$
$$x_2=\frac{33549067}{32130245}\approx 1.04416$$ which are better than the previous ones and did not require the computation of square roots.